# Transform translate has poor performance on IE

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, transform, translate

I am currently creating a floormap using HTML and Canvas.

Here is the test url : http://test.fastcoding.jp/clem/floormap/

Map image for each zoom level is cut into pieces (with PHP), and map is rebuilt using HTML divs with different transform: translate() positions.

On mouse wheel events, a scale factor is applied to each divs, and once the scale become 1 the next zoom level is shown.

On mouse drag, translate values are updated.

So now here is the problem.

Everything works fine on Chrome, Safari, but on IE dragging actions are really laggy (a bit laggy in Firefox as well).

Here is my map refresh function that is called on drag :

```
app.refresh_map = function() {

    var curr_map = app.maps[app.curr_zoom];
    var maxI = curr_map.tiles.length-1;
    var maxJ = curr_map.tiles[0].length-1;
    var scale = app.zooms[app.curr_zoom][app.curr_scale];

    for(var i=0; i<=maxI; i++) {     
        for(var j=0; j<=maxJ; j++) {

            var curr_tile = curr_map.tiles[i][j];

            var new_tile = {
                x: curr_tile.x*scale, y: curr_tile.y*scale,
                width: curr_tile.width, height: curr_tile.height
            };

            var selector = ".fm-tiles[data-map='"+app.mapID+"'] .fm-tile[data-zoom='"+app.curr_zoom+"'][data-tile='"+i+"-"+j+"']";
            if ( app.in_screen(new_tile) ) {

                if( $(selector).length==0 ) $tiles.append('<div class="fm-tile" data-zoom="'+app.curr_zoom+'" data-tile="'+i+"-"+j+'"></div>');
                var $tile = $(selector);

                var x = app.pos.x + new_tile.x;
                var y = app.pos.y + new_tile.y;
                x = parseFloat(x.toFixed(2));
                y = parseFloat(y.toFixed(2));

                if(!$tile.hasClass("loaded")) {
                    $tile.css("background", "url('api/results/"+mapID+"/"+app.curr_zoom+"/"+curr_tile.src+"') no-repeat left top");
                    $tile.css("background-size", "100% 100%");
                    $tile.addClass("loaded");
                    $tile.css({
                        "width": curr_tile.width+"px",
                        "height": curr_tile.height+"px"
                    });
                }
                if(app.browser=="ie") {
                    $tile.css({
                        "transform-origin": "0% 0%",
                        "-ms-transform": "translate("+x+"px,"+y+"px) scale("+scale+","+scale+")"
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $tile.css({
                        "transform-origin": "0px 0px 0px",
                        "-webkit-transform": "translate3d("+x+"px,"+y+"px, 0px) scale("+scale+","+scale+") rotate(0.01deg)",
                        "-moz-transform": "translate3d("+x+"px,"+y+"px, 0px) scale("+scale+","+scale+") rotate(0.01deg)",
                        "transform": "translate3d("+x+"px,"+y+"px, 0px) scale("+scale+","+scale+") rotate(0.01deg)"
                    });
                }
                if(!$tile.is(":visible")) {
                    $tile.show().addClass("shown");
                }

            }
            else {
                if($(selector).length!=0){
                    $(selector).hide();
                } 
            }

        }
    }

    $(".fm-tiles[data-map='"+app.mapID+"'] .fm-tile:not([data-zoom='"+app.curr_zoom+"'])").hide();

}
```

I know it is possible to make it smooth because there is this map which work perfectly on any browser : http://okayamaeki-sc.jp/floorguide/#/sunste2f

I looked a bit the code but it is ugglyfied so a bit hard to understand.
I know that it uses different transform and transform-origin according to the browser and that it is using a sort of easing, but I don't know if it's the reason why it is so smooth.

Does anyone have any clue ?

Thanks.